# Multiple GroupBy in Cascading

Tags: cascading

I have my requirements as follows. Below is my input tuple.

```
Documents, PatternA, PatternB      
['D1'    ,  'S1'   ,   'V1']
['D1'    ,  'S1'   ,   'V2']
['D1'    ,  'S2'   ,   'V1']
['D1'    ,  'S2'   ,   'V2']
['D2'    ,  'S1'   ,   'V1']
['D2'    ,  'S1'   ,   'V2']
['D2'    ,  'S1'   ,   'V3']
['D2'    ,  'S2'   ,   'V1']
['D2'    ,  'S2'   ,   'V2']
['D2'    ,  'S2'   ,   'V3']
['D2'    ,  'S3'   ,   'V1']
['D2'    ,  'S3'   ,   'V2']
['D2'    ,  'S3'   ,   'V3']
```

Based on my requirements I have to find  how many  PatternA, PatternB  pair occurred in  how many number of Documents.
For example S1,V1 pair occurred  in D1 and D2 (Two Documents) based on  above input tuple.
Example:

```
['D1','S1','V1'] -input tuple line 1 
['D2','S1','V1'] -input  tuple line 5
```

count of PatternA, PatternB pair  occured in the Documents  called X ( i need this X for the result output )
below is my  code to achieve  the above requirements.

```
 Pipe pipe = new Pipe("All the above 13 records"); 
  Fields groupFieldsX = new Fields("PatternA","PatternB"); //for calculating  X
  xPipe = new GroupBy(pipe, groupFieldsX, new Fields("PatternA","PatternB"));
  xPipe = new Every(xPipe, Fields.ALL, new Count(new Fields("Xcount")), Fields.ALL);
  xPipe = new Each(xPipe, new Debug());
```

Result X

```
['S1', 'V1', '2']
['S1', 'V2', '2']
['S1', 'V3', '1']
['S2', 'V1', '2']
['S2', 'V2', '2']
['S2', 'V3', '1']
['S3', 'V1', '1']
['S3', 'V2', '1']
['S3', 'V3', '1']
```

tuples count: 9

Until here  I am good.

Now I need to find out the Y.  Y is nothing but number of  time PatternA occurred  in Documents (only unique value should be picked)
For example:

```
D1, S1
D2, S1
D1, S1
```

(here S1 occurred only in 2 Documents, because the third is duplicated. So Y count is 2)

Below is my code to calculate the Y value

```
  pipe = new Retain(pipe, new Fields("Documents","PatternA"));// from the 13     tuples I take only Documents,PatternA
  pipe = new Unique(pipe, new Fields("Documents","PatternA"));// eliminate   dupilcate
  Fields groupFieldsY = new Fields("Documents","PatternA"); //for calculating Y
  Pipe yPipe = new GroupBy(pipe, groupFieldsY);
  yPipe = new Every(yPipe,Fields.ALL, new Count(new Fields("Ycount")), Fields.ALL);
  yPipe = new Each(yPipe, new Debug());
```

Result Y

```
['D1', 'S1', '1']
['D1', 'S2', '1']
['D2', 'S1', '1']
['D2', 'S2', '1']
['D2', 'S3', '1']
```

tuples count: 5

Now here is the final output what I need from Result X & Result Y.

Report:

```
PatternA, PatternB, Xcount, Documents, Ycount
 S1     ,  V1     ,  2    ,  D1,D2  ,   2
 S1     ,  V2     ,  2    ,  D1,D2  ,   2
```

...report continue

Now someone suggest me how can I arrive the Report from the total of 9+5 tuple output.  Also suggest me if there is any other efficient

way to calculate the X and Y values and produce the Report.

Thanks in Advance for your input/suggestion/solution.